# Convert Excel Text time to value

Tags: excel, timestamp

I have this format in an excel column:

00:03:30

It represents 3 minutes and 30 seconds.

I need to convert it to a numerical format where I can add them.

Is there a special kind of format I can use?

Comment: DateTime objects should support addition.

Comment: but i dont think its a date time object. its imported from my mobile carrier's website. its minutes per call. but it comes across as just general text i guess.

Comment: Try changing the format of the column to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is text then you can't change that by changing the formatting

Check whether the data is text by using this formula applied to one of the cells

`=ISNUMBER(A2)`

That will presumably give you FALSE

Assuming there are no additional characters in your data you can convert with "text to columns" - just select column of "times" then use

`Data > Text to Columns > Finish`

Now you should be able to sum and/or re-format the data